# How display multi videos with threading using tkinter in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, tkinter

I recently created a program which displays multi video sources from 2 ip cameras with opencv.
but I decided to create UI for my application, and now, It's not so clear for me that how I can implement it using multi threading method.

here is the code I used to display only one camera in TKinter GUI:

```
import tkinter
import cv2
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk
import time

class App:
    def __init__(self, window, window_title, video_source=0):
        self.window = window
        self.window.title(window_title)
        self.video_source = video_source
        
        # open video source (by default this will try to open the computer webcam)
        self.vid = MyVideoCapture(self.video_source)
        
        # Create a canvas that can fit the above video source size
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window, width = self.vid.width, height = self.vid.height)
        self.canvas.pack()
         
        # Button that lets the user take a snapshot
        self.btn_snapshot=tkinter.Button(window, text="Snapshot", width=50, command=self.snapshot)
        self.btn_snapshot.pack(anchor=tkinter.CENTER, expand=True)
         
        # After it is called once, the update method will be automatically called every delay milliseconds
        self.delay = 15
        self.update()
         
        self.window.mainloop()
     
    def snapshot(self):
        # Get a frame from the video source
        ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame()
        
        if ret:
            cv2.imwrite("frame-" + time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S") + ".jpg", cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
    
    def update(self):
        # Get a frame from the video source
        ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame()
        
        if ret:
            self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = PIL.Image.fromarray(frame))
            self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = self.photo, anchor = tkinter.NW)
        
        self.window.after(self.delay, self.update)
    
     
class MyVideoCapture:
    def __init__(self, video_source=0):
        # Open the video source
        self.vid = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)
        if not self.vid.isOpened():
            raise ValueError("Unable to open video source", video_source)
    
        # Get video source width and height
        self.width = self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
        self.height = self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    
    def get_frame(self):
        if self.vid.isOpened():
            ret, frame = self.vid.read()
            if ret:
                # Return a boolean success flag and the current frame converted to BGR
                return (ret, cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            else:
                return (ret, None)
        else:
            return (ret, None)
    
    # Release the video source when the object is destroyed
    def __del__(self):
        if self.vid.isOpened():
            self.vid.release()
 
 # Create a window and pass it to the Application object
App(tkinter.Tk(), "Tkinter and OpenCV")
```

and here was my previous application which displays multi video sources in different threads:

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2
import time

class VideoWriterWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, video_file_name, src=0):
        # Create a VideoCapture object
        self.frame_name = str(src)
        self.video_file = video_file_name
        self.video_file_name = video_file_name + '.avi'
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)

        # Default resolutions of the frame are obtained (system dependent)
        self.frame_width = int(self.capture.get(3))
        self.frame_height = int(self.capture.get(4))

        # Set up codec and output video settings
        self.codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')
        self.output_video = cv2.VideoWriter(self.video_file_name, self.codec, 30, (self.frame_width, self.frame_height))

        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

        # Start another thread to show/save frames
        self.start_recording()
        print('initialized {}'.format(self.video_file))

    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()

    def show_frame(self):
        # Display frames in main program
        if self.status:
            cv2.imshow(self.frame_name, self.frame)

        # Press Q on keyboard to stop recording
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            self.capture.release()
            self.output_video.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            exit(1)

    def save_frame(self):
        # Save obtained frame into video output file
        self.output_video.write(self.frame)

    def start_recording(self):
        # Create another thread to show/save frames
        def start_recording_thread():
            while True:
                try:
                    self.show_frame()
                    self.save_frame()
                except AttributeError:
                    pass
        self.recording_thread = Thread(target=start_recording_thread, args=())
        self.recording_thread.daemon = True
        self.recording_thread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    src1 = 'Your link1'
    video_writer_widget1 = VideoWriterWidget('Camera 1', src1)
    src2 = 'Your link2'
    video_writer_widget2 = VideoWriterWidget('Camera 2', src2)
    src3 = 'Your link3'
    video_writer_widget3 = VideoWriterWidget('Camera 3', src3)

    # Since each video player is in its own thread, we need to keep the main thread alive.
    # Keep spinning using time.sleep() so the background threads keep running
    # Threads are set to daemon=True so they will automatically die 
    # when the main thread dies
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
```

can someone help me how I can use my previous code (display multi cameras) in my new application using tkinter with threading?

Comment: why not use `root.after` for many streams - without using `threads`. OR keep cameras on list and use one `root.after` with `for`-loop to work with many cameras on list.

Comment: for evey frame you create new image on canvas - `create_image()` - but this doesn't remove previous image from canvas so it may use more memory. `create_image` gives you image's ID - `image_id = create_image(...)` which you could use to delete previous image. Or you could replace image in `PhotoImage` like `self.photo["image"] = PIL.Image....` and then you don't have to replace it on canvas.

Comment: threading may have one big problem - Tkinter (like many other GUIs) doesn't like to use widgets in threads and you would have to send frame from thread to main thread - ie. using `queue` - and it would need to use `root.after` to get check if there is new frame in queue, get it from queue and update widget in main thread. It would need more work then do all directly in main thread. Thread could be useful if you want to make some processing on image - detect faces, detect motion, etc.

Comment: maybe you would even use `Frame` to create widget with single camera, single canvas and later use it many times in `App` to have many streams in program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tkinter` (like many other GUIs) doesn't like to use widgets in threads so first I would try to run all in main process without threads.

In example I moved most of code to class based on `tkinter.Frame` to create widget
which I can use many times with different streams. Because I have only one camera (and system can't use the same camera many times) so I found some external stream/file to test it. Because stream sends very big image so I change size to `400, 300`

Code works fast when it doesn't have to resize image.
When it has to resize image then sometimes it has problem but still it is OK.

[image]

---

```
import tkinter
import cv2
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk
import time

# widgets with canvas and camera

class tkCamera(tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, window, video_source=0):
        super().__init__(window)
        
        self.window = window
        
        #self.window.title(window_title)
        self.video_source = video_source
        self.vid = MyVideoCapture(self.video_source)

        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window, width=self.vid.width, height=self.vid.height)
        self.canvas.pack()
         
        # Button that lets the user take a snapshot
        self.btn_snapshot = tkinter.Button(window, text="Snapshot", width=50, command=self.snapshot)
        self.btn_snapshot.pack(anchor=tkinter.CENTER, expand=True)
         
        # After it is called once, the update method will be automatically called every delay milliseconds
        self.delay = 15
        self.update_widget()

    def snapshot(self):
        # Get a frame from the video source
        ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame()
        
        if ret:
            cv2.imwrite("frame-" + time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S") + ".jpg", cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
    
    def update_widget(self):
        # Get a frame from the video source
        ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame()
        
        if ret:
            self.image = PIL.Image.fromarray(frame)
            self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.image)
            self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = self.photo, anchor = tkinter.NW)
        
        self.window.after(self.delay, self.update_widget)


class App:

    def __init__(self, window, window_title, video_source1=0, video_source2=0):
        self.window = window

        self.window.title(window_title)
        
        # open video source (by default this will try to open the computer webcam)
        self.vid1 = tkCamera(window, video_source1)
        self.vid1.pack()
        
        self.vid2 = tkCamera(window, video_source2)
        self.vid2.pack()
        
        # Create a canvas that can fit the above video source size
         
        self.window.mainloop()
     
    
     
class MyVideoCapture:
    def __init__(self, video_source=0):
        # Open the video source
        self.vid = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)
        if not self.vid.isOpened():
            raise ValueError("Unable to open video source", video_source)
    
        # Get video source width and height
        self.width = self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
        self.height = self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 300
    
    def get_frame(self):
        if self.vid.isOpened():
            ret, frame = self.vid.read()
            if ret:
                frame = cv2.resize(frame, (400, 300))
                # Return a boolean success flag and the current frame converted to BGR
                return (ret, cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            else:
                return (ret, None)
        else:
            return (ret, None)
    
    # Release the video source when the object is destroyed
    def __del__(self):
        if self.vid.isOpened():
            self.vid.release()
 
# Create a window and pass it to the Application object
App(tkinter.Tk(), "Tkinter and OpenCV", 0, 'https://imageserver.webcamera.pl/rec/krupowki-srodek/latest.mp4')
```

---

If you plan to process frame - ie. detect motion or faces - then code from `get_frame` could run in separated thead. Thread would process frames all time and assign to `self.frame` and `get_frame()` should only return current `self.frame`.

See similar idea on blog `pyImageSearch` in
[Increasing webcam FPS with Python and OpenCV](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/12/21/increasing-webcam-fps-with-python-and-opencv/).

Probably you could even use

```
 from imutils.video import WebcamVideoStream
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version still without threading but with list of sources so it can display many cameras. But for more then 2 sources it has problem to display - so this would need to use `threads`.

**BTW:** widgets and windows in `tkinter` already have method `update()` so I renamed it to `update_frame()`

In `snapshot` I used `pilow.image.save()` so I don't have to read new frame and convert to `BGR` - and I can take snapshot when stream is stoped. `Button` stops only replacing image on canvas but not stop reading frames from stream in thread - so other function could still process or record stream.

---

```
import tkinter
import cv2
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk
import time

class MyVideoCapture:

    def __init__(self, video_source=0, width=None, height=None):
    
        # Open the video source
        self.vid = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)
        if not self.vid.isOpened():
            raise ValueError("Unable to open video source", video_source)

        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    
        # Get video source width and height
        if not self.width:
            self.width = int(self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))    # convert float to int
        if not self.height:
            self.height = int(self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))  # convert float to int

        self.ret = False
        self.frame = None

    def process(self):
        ret = False
        frame = None
        
        if self.vid.isOpened():
            ret, frame = self.vid.read()
            if ret:
                frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.width, self.height))
                frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        
        self.ret = ret
        self.frame = frame
        
    def get_frame(self):
        self.process()  # later run in thread
        return self.ret, self.frame
    
    # Release the video source when the object is destroyed
    def __del__(self):
        if self.vid.isOpened():
            self.vid.release()
 
 
class tkCamera(tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, window, video_source=0, width=None, height=None):
        super().__init__(window)
        
        self.window = window
        
        #self.window.title(window_title)
        self.video_source = video_source
        self.vid = MyVideoCapture(self.video_source, width, height)

        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window, width=self.vid.width, height=self.vid.height)
        self.canvas.pack()
         
        # Button that lets the user take a snapshot
        self.btn_snapshot = tkinter.Button(window, text="Snapshot", width=50, command=self.snapshot)
        self.btn_snapshot.pack(anchor='center', expand=True)
         
        # After it is called once, the update method will be automatically called every delay milliseconds
        self.delay = 15
        self.update_widget()

    def snapshot(self):
        # Get a frame from the video source
        ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame()
        
        if ret:
            cv2.imwrite("frame-" + time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S") + ".jpg", cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
    
    def update_widget(self):
        # Get a frame from the video source
        ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame()
        
        if ret:
            self.image = PIL.Image.fromarray(frame)
            self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.image)
            self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = self.photo, anchor = tkinter.NW)
        
        self.window.after(self.delay, self.update_widget)


class App:

    def __init__(self, window, window_title, video_sources):
        self.window = window

        self.window.title(window_title)
        
        self.vids = []
        
        for source in video_sources:
            vid = tkCamera(window, source, 400, 300)
            vid.pack()
            self.vids.append(vid)
        
        # Create a canvas that can fit the above video source size
         
        self.window.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':     

    sources = [
        0, 
        #'https://imageserver.webcamera.pl/rec/krupowki-srodek/latest.mp4',
        #'https://imageserver.webcamera.pl/rec/skolnity/latest.mp4',
        'https://imageserver.webcamera.pl/rec/krakow4/latest.mp4',
    ]
    
        
    # Create a window and pass it to the Application object
    App(tkinter.Tk(), "Tkinter and OpenCV", sources)
```

---

**EDIT**

Version which uses `threads` to read and process frames. I add `time(1/fps)` to process it only when it is needed so it works smoother. For delay `15` it freezed sometimes.

I uses sources which have only 24 seconds so after few seconds they stop.

[image]

---

```
import tkinter
import cv2
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk
import time
import threading

class MyVideoCapture:

    def __init__(self, video_source=0, width=None, height=None, fps=None):
    
        self.video_source = video_source
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.fps = fps
        
        # Open the video source
        self.vid = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)
        if not self.vid.isOpened():
            raise ValueError("[MyVideoCapture] Unable to open video source", video_source)

        # Get video source width and height
        if not self.width:
            self.width = int(self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))    # convert float to int
        if not self.height:
            self.height = int(self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))  # convert float to int
        if not self.fps:
            self.fps = int(self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))  # convert float to int

        # default value at start        
        self.ret = False
        self.frame = None

        # start thread
        self.running = True
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.process)
        self.thread.start()
        
    def process(self):
        while self.running:
            ret, frame = self.vid.read()
            
            if ret:
                # process image
                frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.width, self.height))
                frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            else:
                print('[MyVideoCapture] stream end:', self.video_source)
                # TODO: reopen stream
                self.running = False
                break
                
            # assign new frame
            self.ret = ret
            self.frame = frame
            
            # sleep for next frame
            time.sleep(1/self.fps)
        
    def get_frame(self):
        return self.ret, self.frame
    
    # Release the video source when the object is destroyed
    def __del__(self):
        # stop thread
        if self.running:
            self.running = False
            self.thread.join()

        # relase stream
        if self.vid.isOpened():
            self.vid.release()
            
 
class tkCamera(tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, window, text="", video_source=0, width=None, height=None):
        super().__init__(window)
        
        self.window = window
        
        #self.window.title(window_title)
        self.video_source = video_source
        self.vid = MyVideoCapture(self.video_source, width, height)

        self.label = tkinter.Label(self, text=text)
        self.label.pack()
        
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self, width=self.vid.width, height=self.vid.height)
        self.canvas.pack()

        # Button that lets the user take a snapshot
        self.btn_snapshot = tkinter.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.start)
        self.btn_snapshot.pack(anchor='center', side='left')
        
        self.btn_snapshot = tkinter.Button(self, text="Stop", command=self.stop)
        self.btn_snapshot.pack(anchor='center', side='left')
         
        # Button that lets the user take a snapshot
        self.btn_snapshot = tkinter.Button(self, text="Snapshot", command=self.snapshot)
        self.btn_snapshot.pack(anchor='center', side='left')
         
        # After it is called once, the update method will be automatically called every delay milliseconds
        # calculate delay using `FPS`
        self.delay = int(1000/self.vid.fps)

        print('[tkCamera] source:', self.video_source)
        print('[tkCamera] fps:', self.vid.fps, 'delay:', self.delay)
        
        self.image = None
        
        self.running = True
        self.update_frame()

    def start(self):
        if not self.running:
            self.running = True
            self.update_frame()

    def stop(self):
        if self.running:
           self.running = False
    
    def snapshot(self):
        # Get a frame from the video source
        #ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame()
        #if ret:
        #    cv2.imwrite(time.strftime("frame-%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S.jpg"), cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
        
        # Save current frame in widget - not get new one from camera - so it can save correct image when it stoped
        if self.image:
            self.image.save(time.strftime("frame-%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S.jpg"))
            
    def update_frame(self):
        # widgets in tkinter already have method `update()` so I have to use different name -

        # Get a frame from the video source
        ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame()
        
        if ret:
            self.image = PIL.Image.fromarray(frame)
            self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.image)
            self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo, anchor='nw')
        
        if self.running:
            self.window.after(self.delay, self.update_frame)


class App:

    def __init__(self, window, window_title, video_sources):
        self.window = window

        self.window.title(window_title)
        
        self.vids = []

        columns = 2
        for number, source in enumerate(video_sources):
            text, stream = source
            vid = tkCamera(self.window, text, stream, 400, 300)
            x = number % columns
            y = number // columns
            vid.grid(row=y, column=x)
            self.vids.append(vid)
        
        self.window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)
        self.window.mainloop()
    
    def on_closing(self, event=None):
        print('[App] stoping threads')
        for source in self.vids:
            source.vid.running = False
        print('[App] exit')
        self.window.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':     

    sources = [
        ('me', 0), 
        ('Zakopane, Poland', 'https://imageserver.webcamera.pl/rec/krupowki-srodek/latest.mp4'),
        ('Kraków, Poland', 'https://imageserver.webcamera.pl/rec/krakow4/latest.mp4'),
        ('Warszawa, Poland', 'https://imageserver.webcamera.pl/rec/warszawa/latest.mp4'),
        #('Baltic See, Poland', 'https://imageserver.webcamera.pl/rec/chlopy/latest.mp4'),
        #('Mountains, Poland', 'https://imageserver.webcamera.pl/rec/skolnity/latest.mp4'),
    ]
        
    # Create a window and pass it to the Application object
    App(tkinter.Tk(), "Tkinter and OpenCV", sources)
```

---

**EDIT**

Version which can record video.

`cv2` needs frame with BGR color to save it correctly so I had to save it before frame is converted to RGB.

I moved most code to `MyVideoCapture` so it can be used even without `tkinter`. I also add option in `MyVideoCapture` to get image as `cv2 array` or `pillow.image` - so now it converts to `pillow` inside `thread` so main thread doesn't have to do it.

---

```
import tkinter
import cv2
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk
import time
import threading

class MyVideoCapture:

    def __init__(self, video_source=0, width=None, height=None, fps=None):
    
        self.video_source = video_source
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.fps = fps
        
        # Open the video source
        self.vid = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)
        if not self.vid.isOpened():
            raise ValueError("[MyVideoCapture] Unable to open video source", video_source)

        # Get video source width and height
        if not self.width:
            self.width = int(self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))    # convert float to int
        if not self.height:
            self.height = int(self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))  # convert float to int
        if not self.fps:
            self.fps = int(self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))  # convert float to int

        # default value at start        
        self.ret = False
        self.frame = None
        
        self.convert_color = cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB
        #self.convert_color = cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY
        self.convert_pillow = True
        
        # default values for recording        
        self.recording = False
        self.recording_filename = 'output.mp4'
        self.recording_writer = None
        
        # start thread
        self.running = True
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.process)
        self.thread.start()
        
    def start_recording(self, filename=None):
        if self.recording:
            print('[MyVideoCapture] already recording:', self.recording_filename)
        else:
            # VideoWriter constructors
            #.mp4 = codec id 2
            if filename:
                self.recording_filename = filename
            else:
                self.recording_filename = time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d %H.%M.%S", time.localtime()) + ".avi"
            #fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'I420') # .avi
            #fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V') # .avi
            fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP42') # .avi
            #fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'AVC1') # error libx264
            #fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264') # error libx264
            #fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'WRAW') # error --- no information ---
            #fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MPEG') # .avi 30fps
            #fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG') # .avi
            #fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID') # .avi
            #fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H265') # error 
            self.recording_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(self.recording_filename, fourcc, self.fps, (self.width, self.height))
            self.recording = True
            print('[MyVideoCapture] started recording:', self.recording_filename)
                   
    def stop_recording(self):
        if not self.recording:
            print('[MyVideoCapture] not recording')
        else:
            self.recording = False
            self.recording_writer.release() 
            print('[MyVideoCapture] stop recording:', self.recording_filename)
               
    def record(self, frame):
        # write frame to file         
        if self.recording_writer and self.recording_writer.isOpened():
            self.recording_writer.write(frame)
 
     
    def process(self):
        while self.running:
            ret, frame = self.vid.read()
            
            if ret:
                # process image
                frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.width, self.height))

                # it has to record before converting colors
                if self.recording:
                    self.record(frame)
                    
                if self.convert_pillow:
                    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                    frame = PIL.Image.fromarray(frame)
            else:
                print('[MyVideoCapture] stream end:', self.video_source)
                # TODO: reopen stream
                self.running = False
                if self.recording:
                    self.stop_recording()
                break
                
            # assign new frame
            self.ret = ret
            self.frame = frame

            # sleep for next frame
            time.sleep(1/self.fps)
        
    def get_frame(self):
        return self.ret, self.frame
    
    # Release the video source when the object is destroyed
    def __del__(self):
        # stop thread
        if self.running:
            self.running = False
            self.thread.join()

        # relase stream
        if self.vid.isOpened():
            self.vid.release()
            
 
class tkCamera(tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, window, text="", video_source=0, width=None, height=None):
        super().__init__(window)
        
        self.window = window
        
        #self.window.title(window_title)
        self.video_source = video_source
        self.vid = MyVideoCapture(self.video_source, width, height)

        self.label = tkinter.Label(self, text=text)
        self.label.pack()
        
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self, width=self.vid.width, height=self.vid.height)
        self.canvas.pack()

        # Button that lets the user take a snapshot
        self.btn_snapshot = tkinter.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.start)
        self.btn_snapshot.pack(anchor='center', side='left')
        
        self.btn_snapshot = tkinter.Button(self, text="Stop", command=self.stop)
        self.btn_snapshot.pack(anchor='center', side='left')
         
        # Button that lets the user take a snapshot
        self.btn_snapshot = tkinter.Button(self, text="Snapshot", command=self.snapshot)
        self.btn_snapshot.pack(anchor='center', side='left')
         
        # After it is called once, the update method will be automatically called every delay milliseconds
        # calculate delay using `FPS`
        self.delay = int(1000/self.vid.fps)

        print('[tkCamera] source:', self.video_source)
        print('[tkCamera] fps:', self.vid.fps, 'delay:', self.delay)
        
        self.image = None
        
        self.running = True
        self.update_frame()

    def start(self):
        #if not self.running:
        #    self.running = True
        #    self.update_frame()
        self.vid.start_recording()

    def stop(self):
        #if self.running:
        #   self.running = False
        self.vid.stop_recording()
    
    def snapshot(self):
        # Get a frame from the video source
        #ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame()
        #if ret:
        #    cv2.imwrite(time.strftime("frame-%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S.jpg"), cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
        
        # Save current frame in widget - not get new one from camera - so it can save correct image when it stoped
        if self.image:
            self.image.save(time.strftime("frame-%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S.jpg"))
            
    def update_frame(self):
        # widgets in tkinter already have method `update()` so I have to use different name -

        # Get a frame from the video source
        ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame()
        
        if ret:
            #self.image = PIL.Image.fromarray(frame)
            self.image = frame
            self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.image)
            self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo, anchor='nw')
        
        if self.running:
            self.window.after(self.delay, self.update_frame)


class App:

    def __init__(self, window, window_title, video_sources):
        self.window = window

        self.window.title(window_title)
        
        self.vids = []

        columns = 2
        for number, source in enumerate(video_sources):
            text, stream = source
            vid = tkCamera(self.window, text, stream, 400, 300)
            x = number % columns
            y = number // columns
            vid.grid(row=y, column=x)
            self.vids.append(vid)
        
        self.window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)
        self.window.mainloop()
    
    def on_closing(self, event=None):
        print('[App] stoping threads')
        for source in self.vids:
            source.vid.running = False
        print('[App] exit')
        self.window.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':     

    sources = [
        ('me', 0), 
        ('Zakopane, Poland', 'https://imageserver.webcamera.pl/rec/krupowki-srodek/latest.mp4'),
        ('Kraków, Poland', 'https://imageserver.webcamera.pl/rec/krakow4/latest.mp4'),
        ('Warszawa, Poland', 'https://imageserver.webcamera.pl/rec/warszawa/latest.mp4'),
        #('Baltic See, Poland', 'https://imageserver.webcamera.pl/rec/chlopy/latest.mp4'),
        #('Mountains, Poland', 'https://imageserver.webcamera.pl/rec/skolnity/latest.mp4'),
    ]
        
    # Create a window and pass it to the Application object
    App(tkinter.Tk(), "Tkinter and OpenCV", sources)
```

---

**EDIT:**

I created version which can select source - so it can display recorded videos.

This code is chaotic. Dialog window could be in separated class.

I can't put code here because answer has limitation to 30000 characters.

I put it on GitHub: [python-cv2-streams-viewer](https://github.com/furas/python-cv2-streams-viewer/)

[image]

---

Comment: tnx for your answer, but my problem is how to run cameras using threads, because I'm gonna run more than 2 cameras. and it may have lots of delay to display.
can you update your answer using threads?

Comment: in second version you have to run in thread only function `process()` - I put code later.

Comment: tnx a lot! you really saved me. I had another question, If I want to record the frames and replay each of them.. How it might be possible?

Comment: I have old example which use cv2 to record in file but it works with single camera and doesn't use `threading` - [furas/python-examples - cv2 - record-file](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/cv2/record-file). But I think you would save frame in `update_frame` in `tkCamera` (with some `if record:`, `if create_new_file:`). Eventually move it to `MyVideoCapture`. Later I will try to do this - and this is why I add buttons in `Start`, `Stop` in last code.

Comment: I added code which record video in file. I put this code inside `MyVideoCapture` so it can be used also without `tkinter` - ie. it could be use with other GUI - PyQt, PyGTK, web page, or even without GUI.

Comment: furas, tnxx a lot for your clean answer, as I see your last code,  each thread (cap) records it's frame separately, am I right?

Comment: and if I wanted to play back the recorded videos, what I have to do? should I load the  video file from file browser and run it in the same window?

Comment: yes, cap read and write in separated thread - I even move `PIL.Image.fromarray(frame)` to `thread`. This way main thread (GUI) doesn't have to read, doesn't have to resize, doesn't have to record, doesn't have convert to `PIL.Image`. Recorded video you can watch in external video player or web browser. You can also use it as source in `tkCamera`

Comment: I created version which display dialog window to select source - predefined or open file. I couldn't put it in answer because it has limitation to 30000 characters - so I put it on GitHub: [python-cv2-streams-viewer](https://github.com/furas/python-cv2-streams-viewer/)