# How to make videocapture stream in a for loop to stram multiple cameras

Tags: python, numpy, loops, opencv, video-streaming

I am trying to make this videocapture opencv2 python script allow me to do multiple video streams from my laptop cam and USB cams and I succeeded (with help of youtube) to do so only every time I add a camera I have to edit the line of code and add another videocapture line and another frame and another `cv2.imshow`. But I want to edit the video capture code in a way that allows me to stream as many cameras as detected without the need to add a line every time there is a camera using a loop. I'm obviously new here so accept my apologies if the solution is too simple.

This is the code that allows me to stream multiple cameras but with adding a line for each camera.

```py
import urllib.request
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Defining URL for camera
video_capture_0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
video_capture_1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    
    ret0, frame0 = video_capture_0.read()
    ret1, frame1 = video_capture_1.read()
    

    if (ret0):
        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('Cam 0', frame0)

    if (ret1):
        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('Cam 1', frame1)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture_0.release()
video_capture_1.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried making a list `camlist = [i for i in range(100)]` and then adding that to a for loop that keeps adding it to videocapture. But I believe that's a mess so I deleted the code plus that doesn't seem so effective.

Comment: To achieve this, it seems that you need other tools. If only wanna use python and opencv, you ll have to control cameras in a loop always which is not a good way(this loop can be a thread). If you really need to do that you should use new tools to check the camera connections synchronously in bacground.

Comment: you should use `list` to keep camers, and then you can use `for`-loop to work with all cameras. And you should add `ret,frame` to list so later you can use another `for`-loop to work with all results. And finally you can use `for`-loop to`release()` all camera. AND then you can add new camera to list and you don't have to change code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to work with many cameras then first you should keep them on list - and then you can use `for`-loop to get all frame. And frames you should also keep on list so later you can use `for`-loop to display them. And finally you can use `for`-loop to release cameras

```
import cv2

#video_captures = [cv2.VideoCapture(x) for x in range(2)]

video_captures = [
    cv2.VideoCapture(0),
    #cv2.VideoCapture(1),
    cv2.VideoCapture('https://imageserver.webcamera.pl/rec/krupowki-srodek/latest.mp4'),
    cv2.VideoCapture('https://imageserver.webcamera.pl/rec/krakow4/latest.mp4'),
    cv2.VideoCapture('https://imageserver.webcamera.pl/rec/warszawa/latest.mp4'),
]    

while True:
 
    results = []
    for cap in video_captures:   
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        results.append( [ret, frame] )

    for number, (ret, frame) in enumerate(results):
        if ret:
            cv2.imshow(f'Cam {number}', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

for cap in video_captures:   
    cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And now if you even add new camera to list then you don't have to change rest of code.

---

But for many cameras it is good to run every camera in separated thread - but still keep all on lists.

---

Few days ago was question: [How display multi videos with threading using tkinter in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65876044/how-display-multi-videos-with-threading-using-tkinter-in-python)