# how to create a root inside a Frame Widget in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, frames

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a Frame inside a window on Tk(), and on this same Frame create a new window with the command window2 = Tk() for example, if not how can we dispaly two Tk() in one program knowing that both need to use the mainloop() function, please?

my code is complex but to illustrate it this is what I want to do

```
window = Tk()

frame = Frame(window)

frame.pack()
```

**window2= Tk(window)** I want to refer to the first window in the second one.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by "on this same Frame create a new window", because you can't create a window inside a frame. For creating a new window, you can use `tk.Toplevel`, read more [here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/toplevel.html)

Comment: I want to create a gui composed of two parts. One part where the user introduce the parameters in one side of the window (frame 1) and display the video with this parameters in the second half of the window(frame 2). that is why i need two mainloop in order to make the video work and for the main program

Comment: look at here < https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65876044/how-display-multi-videos-with-threading-using-tkinter-in-python>